# How to access the a particular value from the data table?

Tags: c#

I want to access value of 2nd row 1st column from an existing data table..
I tried with this code..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Aqua");
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i]["SlNo"];
}
```

Data table name is "Aqua"..
But nothing is working..
Help me out..

Comment: Where do you fill that DataTable? As is it seems to be pretty empty

Comment: from where to where you want to transfer data ? from `datagridItemEntry to dt` or from `dt to datagridItemEntry` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..It may help you out.

```
string temp;
String query="Your Query that retrieves the data you want";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);//con is your connection string
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
con.Open();//Open your connection to database
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
    temp=dt.Rows[0]["SlNo"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just declaring the `DataTable` but **no data is loaded** so your loop wont execute as the `dt.Rows.Count` is zero. This is what is expected behavior. You probably need to load data before the loop.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("Aqua");
 //Load data in to data table here.
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
        datagridItemEntry.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i]["SlNo"];
 }
```

**Edit** To access Second Row first column, then just put a condition to assure you have required number of rows and columns, if the rows and column count could be less then the required.

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows.Columns.Count > 0)
   str = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
```

Comment: Also, if you only want the 2nd Row, 1st Column then you can access it without looping with dt.Tables["Aqua"].Rows[1][0], after first ensuring that there are at least 2 rows and 1 column in that dataset.